# Solr displays incorrect physical memory usage per to ubuntu's free -m command

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, memory, solr

I've a Linode 4GB ram and I installed on it Apache Solr and Java 8, and currently running couple of jars in the background. I didn't use Solr yet, I only installed it and left it running. After a day or so I went to Solr's page on my server and saw this:
[Solr says 98% of memory is used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysuNQ.png)

But when I type free -m in the console:
[Less than 32% is used!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x33Tb.png)

And when I used top command the total memory usage is less than 32% !

Comment: Are you sure that Solr isn't talking about the memory you've set aside for the JVM?

Comment: I don't believe so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr apparently includes "buff/cache" into that number. If you add it to "used" you get 98%.

That memory is reclaimable, so you shouldn't be worried. Operating system is just using RAM for disk cache as much as possible.